# VirtualBox: Installing Guest Additions on Ubuntu 12.10 as guest OS

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I use Windows 7 as host, and Ubuntu 12.10 Remix (Ubuntu with pure Gnome) as guest.

Everything working ok. I installed VBoxAdditions in regular way - using corresponding command in VirtualBox VM manager, and then running `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` script from mounted drive. Installation process also seems like OK.
BUT, in `/var/log/vboxadd-install.log` I see this:

```
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.2.6/source ->
                 /usr/src/vboxguest-4.2.6

DKMS: add completed.
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 3.5.0-17-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Failed to install using DKMS, attempting to install without
/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile.include.header:97: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

Then Im follow instructions and trying to install `linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic`, and getting this (last two lines in log after `apt-get`):

```
Error! Problems with depmod detected.  Automatically uninstalling this module.
DKMS: Install Failed (depmod problems).  Module rolled back to built state.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install the linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic package.

Since virtualbox compiles its module against the current kernel, it needs at least the C header files for this kernel.

Comment: I updated the question, can you take a look please?

Comment: @GillBates - You need to find a more detail log other then an log entry saying "a problem was detected"